# How to make horizontal list of bootstrap 3 panels responsive?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and struggling to make a horizontal list of panels responsive. My HTML is as below. It renders fine in all browsers but on mobile resolution the text is not responsive. Any ideas what I am missing?

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Sprinkler System <br />Test & Inspection</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, qui ne iudicabit honestatis. Cu utroque adversarium usu, ius ut autem consulatu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Heading for panel</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, qui ne iudicabit honestatis. Cu utroque adversarium usu, ius ut autem consulatu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Heading for panel</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, qui ne iudicabit honestatis. Cu utroque adversarium usu, ius ut autem consulatu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Heading for panel</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, qui ne iudicabit honestatis. Cu utroque adversarium usu, ius ut autem consulatu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it mobile friendly you should have different column sizes at lower resolution. The words are too long to fit within a col-xs-2. You could keep the 4 columns layout by giving it two classes of col-xs-6 and col-sm-3. Once it gets to the smaller resolution the columns will be re arranged appropriately.

Your divs that contain your panels should have the class changed to look like this in each of them. Will give you a 2 column layout at xs resolution and 4 column layout at small and above

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">

</div>
```

If you have issues with the panels not aligning properly on the lower resolution when they are rearranged this might fix the issue:
[Bootstrap fluid row columns with different height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973275/bootstrap-fluid-row-columns-with-different-height)

You just have to add the css class

```
.col-xs-6:nth-child(odd) {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Is the text not supposed to go to next line rather than coming out the panel in small resolutions?

Comment: The text will go to the next line on spaces. But when you have a single word that is many characters it will not split the word. The col-2 uses a width % value. So as the screen shrinks so does with width which causes the word to stick outside the panel. The column layout can be used to increase the width of the column at certain resolutions. That's why I suggest switching to col-xs-6 which would give it 50% width at that resolution rather than 17%~

Comment: Could you give me any example or a link telling how to increase with width of the column on lower resolution