# Twitter Bootstrap very basic layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm stack with a pretty simple question, and I was wondering maybe you can help, cause you always do..
So what I have is a very basic bootstrap layout.. say:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">looong-long-text</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">long-text</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">another long text</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">and another long text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Please check the image link to see what i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNgqn.jpg)

Is there any simple way to achieve such results with bootstrap? Tnx.

Comment: Your question's not too clear, but I'm guessing from your image that you want columns with cells of varying heights which are not affected by the height of the neighboring columns' cells. If so, I think this is a duplicate question of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973275/bootstrap-fluid-row-columns-with-different-height).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two solutions for you:

First (better in my opinion, less code):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div>First</div>
      <div>Third</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div>Second</div>
      <div>Fourth</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Second:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
           <div>First</div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
           <div>Third</div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
           <div>First</div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
           <div>Third</div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKjGzB)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, actually your examples showed me very clearly that although I'm using bootstrap on my project, I don't need it at all in that block. So i just get rid of it and wrote some css. Thanks man, hope i can vote up, but this is my first question and my reputation doesn't allow me to do that)

Comment: No problem, I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try out the new Bootstrap version 4 [card column feature](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#columns).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with bootstrap out of the box, but there are other tools to help you do this.  Here is one of them:
http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: yep, thanks. I used isotope quite a lot, and think this would be also very helpfull.

Comment: @MaxSixblade : No problem, can you mark it as correct?